# HTML - Input text pattern/required attributes conflict with submission

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This simple form is part of a larger web app I have created. Both the required attributes and the pattern attributes only work intermittently. Changing the event listener to "submit" rather than "click" makes the form validation work properly, but then I get a blank page when I submit with the proper input formatting.

```js
var v = "userForm"

document.getElementById("clockIn").addEventListener("click", addLine); //CHANGE TO CLICK FOR WORKING PAGE BUT PATTERN WONT WORK

function addLine() {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var jobNumber = document.getElementById("jnum").value;
  var process = document.querySelector('input[name="operation"]:checked').value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var timeIn = new Date().toLocaleString();

  var info = [firstName, lastName, jobNumber, process, timeIn, comment];
  google.script.run.addEntry(info);
  document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("jnum").value = "";
  document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
  document.querySelector('input[name="operation"]:checked').checked = false;
  alert("Submitted");
}


function addEntry(info) {
  var ssid = "1E81r5Xy**********************W1o4Q";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var oj = ss.getSheetByName("Open Jobs");
  var FileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Drawings & Links");
  while (FileIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = FileIterator.next();
    if (file.getName() == "Drawings & Links") {
      // var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
      var dlid = file.getId();
    }
  }
  var drawingLinks = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dlid);
  var dl = drawingLinks.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  Logger.log(dlid)
  oj.appendRow(info);
}
```

```html
<form id="inputForm">
  <h2 class="subHead">
    Enter Basic Information
  </h2>
  <label for="fname" class="form">First name:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" placeholder="John" required><br><br>
  <label for="lname" class="form">Last name:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" placeholder="Doe" required><br><br>
  <label for="jnum" class="form">Job number:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="jnum" name="jnum" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" pattern="[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="A-1234" required><br>
  <h2 class="subHead">
    Select Operation
  </h2>
  <div>
    <label for="cut" class="form">Cut</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cut" name="operation" value="cut" required><br><br>
    <label for="drill" class="form">Drill</label>
    <input type="radio" id="drill" name="operation" value="drill" required><br><br>
    <label for="fitup" class="form">Fit Up</label>
    <input type="radio" id="fitup" name="operation" value="fit up" required><br><br>
    <label for="weld" class="form">Weld</label>
    <input type="radio" id="weld" name="operation" value="weld" required><br>
  </div>
  <h2 class="subHead">
    Enter Comments
  </h2>
  <input type="text" id="comment" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" placeholder="Optional"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="clockIn" class="button" value="Clock In">
</form>
```

Thanks for the help.

I think I have narrowed the problem down to something to do with the event listener. My thought is that when the "click" event is used, the function runs before the fields are validated by the browser. Yet, I just get a blank page if I use the "submit" event. The function "addEntry" doesn't appear to run; the logged data doesn't appear. Same goes for "addLine" when I add an alert. I have isolated the regex code and verified it works as expected.

Edit: I found that when I remove the event listener on the submit button and add an onsubmit (onsubmit="addLine()") attribute to the form, the alert in "addLine" appears. The "Submitted" alert also appears. Still a blank page after.

Comment: I made a snippet of the code for you.; it throws this error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')"` when you click the button

Answer (score 0):

Your validation fails but that is outside the scope of the question as I see it since you need to check the actual values before you let it submit and probably need a `preventDefault()` on the form if any fail.

You get an error because you cannot filter by `:checked` unless you then determine if that is `null` OR filter it after you get the nodeList.

Here I show a couple of ways to handle the radio buttons; up to you to determine which suits you.

```js
var v = "userForm"

document.getElementById("clockIn").addEventListener("click", addLine); //CHANGE TO CLICK FOR WORKING PAGE BUT PATTERN WONT WORK

function addLine() {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var jobNumber = document.getElementById("jnum").value;

  //demonstrate a few ways to hanlde the radio buttons:
  const procOne = document.querySelector('input[name="operation"]:checked');
  console.log(!!procOne ? procOne.value : procOne, typeof procOne); // null and object if none are checked
  let processValue = procOne === null && typeof procOne === "object" ? "" : procOne.value;
  // querySelectorAll to get all of them so we can filter the list
  const processAll = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="operation"]');
  // creates an array like object of the nodelist; then filters it for checked ones
  const checkProcess = [...processAll].filter(item => item.checked);
  console.log("How many?:", processAll.length);
  console.log("How many checked?:", checkProcess.length);
  console.log(checkProcess.length ? checkProcess.value : "nothing");
  // anther way to get value:
  processValue = checkProcess.length ? checkProcess.value : "nothing"
  if (checkProcess.length !== 0) { //Test if something was checked
    console.log(checkProcess.value); // the value of the checked.
  } else {
    console.log('Nothing checked'); // nothing was checked.
  }

  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var timeIn = new Date().toLocaleString();
  let process = processValue;
  var info = [firstName, lastName, jobNumber, process, timeIn, comment];
  //ccommented out as google is not defined
  //google.script.run.addEntry(info);
  // hitting the DOM again is not a great thing here but left as not part of the question/issue
  document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
  document.getElementById("jnum").value = "";
  document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
  // cannot filter by :checked if none are so check first and set to false
  if (procOne != null) procOne.checked = false;
  alert("Submitted");

}


function addEntry(info) {
  var ssid = "1E81r5Xy**********************W1o4Q";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var oj = ss.getSheetByName("Open Jobs");
  var FileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Drawings & Links");
  while (FileIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = FileIterator.next();
    if (file.getName() == "Drawings & Links") {
      // var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
      var dlid = file.getId();
    }
  }
  var drawingLinks = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dlid);
  var dl = drawingLinks.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  Logger.log(dlid)
  oj.appendRow(info);
}
```

```html
<form id="inputForm">
  <h2 class="subHead">
    Enter Basic Information
  </h2>
  <label for="fname" class="form">First name:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" placeholder="John" required><br><br>
  <label for="lname" class="form">Last name:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" placeholder="Doe" required><br><br>
  <label for="jnum" class="form">Job number:</label><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="jnum" name="jnum" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" pattern="[A-Z]-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="A-1234" required><br>
  <h2 class="subHead">
    Select Operation
  </h2>
  <div>
    <label for="cut" class="form">Cut</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cut" name="operation" value="cut" required><br><br>
    <label for="drill" class="form">Drill</label>
    <input type="radio" id="drill" name="operation" value="drill" required><br><br>
    <label for="fitup" class="form">Fit Up</label>
    <input type="radio" id="fitup" name="operation" value="fit up" required><br><br>
    <label for="weld" class="form">Weld</label>
    <input type="radio" id="weld" name="operation" value="weld" required><br>
  </div>
  <h2 class="subHead">
    Enter Comments
  </h2>
  <input type="text" id="comment" size="25" style="font-size:25px;" placeholder="Optional"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="clockIn" class="button" value="Clock In">
</form>
```